# Changelist conflict in Intellij

Tags: svn, version-control, intellij-idea

I am repeatedly getting the mysterious message in Intellij IDEA IDE:

```
File from non-active changelist is modified
```

I usually pick the "switch changelist" option with no idea what this means. I never got this message until I started undocking my computer and working offline occasionally, now it seems to be happening all the time. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

there is so many option that could cause it.

Try to create your own `.gitignore` in your project root directory. You should add all files here that keep changing over time like intellij configs, build outoput dir, logs. So, if you VCS watching them they are probably in multiple changelists at once.

My ignore list:

```
.idea
*target*
*.iml
*.log
.DS_store
*generated*
```